# Assisting Taiwanese friend who had bags, money and passport stolen in Rome

Tags: passports, italy, security, rome, lost-documents

My friend is travelling to Rome. She is from Taiwan, and her bag has just been stolen, with money and passport in it. I suppose the only thing she can do is to go to the embassy. But I guess this will imply staying a few days more, and she has no money. Is there any way I can send her some? Is there any other solution I am not seeing?

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that the person who contacted you is really your friend (and not somebody who hacked her email, for example?) and she is really in Rome? This could be a scam! It has happened to people I know: somebody gets their email hacked, and sends an email to all their contacts saying they're stuck in a foreign country and to please wire money.

Comment: @Max that is a valid concern and the OP should verify. That being said, unfortunately I have made the experience that Asian women are a prime target for theft and related crime in Italy. Here is the link of the [Taiwanese representation in Rome](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/it/index.html) (in Chinese or Italian).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- She should report the theft to the police and her embassy. The embassy *should* provide emergency travel documents fairly quickly.
- Money can be sent via services like [Western Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Union#Sending_and_receiving_funds), often with new passwords instead of a photo id. (Take care how you transmit the password. And I'm not endorsing that particular provider; I used it for a similar purpose a decade ago, so that was the first name that came to my mind).
- Some embassies will provide emergency loans to their citizens, to travel home. She should ask for that.

Comment: And she should also contact the airline to see if she can get rebooked on another flight free of charge.

Comment: Also some credit cards and banks offer a service when you have to cancel your cards due to theft while travelling that they'll send you money asap.

Comment: If she had Mastercard or Visa I highly recommend cancelling those directly with those companies and **not** with her bank. Both should have an emergency office/number in Italy and know all the best ways to do things. It will not involve a long distance call. She can always contact her bank afterwards. (I've lost Visa card several times overseas. Banks can be extremely incompetent.)

Comment: @hippietrail Can you elaborate on that? My bank has always been *very* on top of it whenever there was a problem.

Comment: Visa's customer support numbers (I think Master's too) are often toll-free. An international call costs a few dollars so that can be a help too.

Comment: @mattdm: You have been lucky. But if you know your bank is good in this regard you should stick with them. My Australian bank has been varying degrees of disappointing. Also I've worked in a backpacker hostel in Australia for over a decade and heard many stories from travelers from other countries. I remember one still hadn't been sorted out after three months. Visa and MC have free support numbers in many countries. If you've lost all your cash and cards you have to think carefully how to spend anything left in your pocket. Food & accommodation. Visa had cash in my hand same day in Nicaragua!

Comment: Skype is very useful for contacting banks etc at minimal cost (pennies a minute).